# Using column value to dict key Polars-Python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, python-polars

```
df_x = (
    df_x
    .filter(pl.col("score") == nested_dict[pl.col("cliente")][pl.col("cluster")])
    )
```

I want to use the column value to dict key.

When I try to run the query above, it gets an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Expr'`

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Can you show an minimal runnable example for `df` and `nested_dict`?

Answer (score 1):

To extend @BileshGanguly's explanation one way to get what you want would be...

```
(
    df_x
    .filter(
        pl.col('score').eq(
            pl.struct('cliente','cluster')
                .map_elements(lambda x: (
                    nested_dict[x['cliente']][x['cluster']]
                    ))
                )
        )
    )
```

This isn't the most efficient way to do it but it's the closest syntax to what you're trying to do. The `map_elements` forces the resolution of your columns to a python function.

If you have a flattened `nested_dict` as its own df then join, that would be more efficient. One way to flatten it could be, there might be more efficient ways.

```
df_nested_prelim=pl.from_dict(nested_dict)
df_nested=[]
for col in df_nested_prelim.columns:
    df_nested.append(
        df_nested_prelim.lazy()
        .select(col).unnest(col)
        .melt(variable_name='cluster', value_name='cluster_value')
        .with_columns(cliente=pl.lit(col))
    )
df_nested=pl.concat(df_nested).collect()
```

then to filter you'd do

```
(
    df
    .join(df_nested, on=['cliente','cluster'])
    .filter(pl.col('score')==pl.col('cluster_value'))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Expr'` because you are trying to use a Polars expression as a dictionary key. In the Polars library, the expressions like `pl.col("cliente")` and `pl.col("cluster")` are not evaluated to their underlying values when passed as keys to a dictionary; they are treated as expression objects, which are unhashable.

To achieve your goal, you need a different approach where you can apply the logic of your nested dictionary to the DataFrame without directly using DataFrame columns as dictionary keys. One way to do this is to iterate over the rows and apply a custom function. This custom function will access the values of `"cliente"` and `"cluster"` for each row and then use these values to get the corresponding value from your nested dictionary. You can set it in a new column and then use that column for comparison in the filter.